# Strange behaviour with CSS property float

Tags: css

I have some blocks inside a container, but with a specific situation not work.

Follow the screenshort:

[image: wrong way]

the blue line must be the initial point of `BLOCK B`, but the block of right is going down it. Why?

codepen: http://codepen.io/faeldix/pen/MyJNXR

ps - my english is not good

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Your pen doesn't seem to reflect this situation. Also, please note that you can embed code in the question itself. Runnable code in fact, if your question is about HTML/CSS/JS.

Comment: Your question just not fulfill the [requirements of a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) but your answer is surprisingly your CSS-Rule `.row { width: 100%; height: 1px; }` could you imagine what s wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This probably happens because `floats` don't work the way you thing they do.

Read more about them on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/float)

I suspect that what you are looking for is `position:absolute`.

Remove your `float:left` from the `.event` and add `position:absolute` instead. Of course then your elements will overlap.

Another solution is to add `position:relative` to `.row` and use `float:left` to the **odd** (those that should be left) `.event` and `float:right` to the **even** (those that should be right) `.event`.